# How can I show only main categories image on home page in magento?

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I wanto to show all main categories on home page with image . i write the following code for tat but it is not show image .

```
    <?php 
    $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
        $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories();
         foreach ($_categories as $_category): 
               $_categoryThumb = $_category->getThumbnail();
               echo $_category->getImageUrl(); 
        ?>
        <li>
             <h2> <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ; ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $this->getUrl() . 'media/catalog/category/' . $_categoryThumb; ?>" alt="<?php echo $_category->getName()?>"/>

             </a>
        </li>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  give the path for src in the img tag as src="<?php echo '/media/catalog/category/'.$_categoryThumb; ?>"
```